# Where does a Controller function receive parameter data from, in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm new to ASP.net, MVC, C# and I'm working on a project that requires me to delete a person from a database. The table has been specifically setup to accommodate adding and deleting users as there will be a small number of people using this particular application.

I'm having trouble understanding where the Controller Post function gets its parameters from.

My controller contains:

```
public ActionResult DeleteUser()
{
    return View(new tblPermission());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteUser(int? id)
{
    if(id == null)
    {
         return View(id);
    }

    Permission.DeleteUser((int)id);

    return RedirectToAction("AdminIndex");
}
```

When I test this function, I'm always hitting the id == null condition because I'm not passing in the id. What confuses me is, how do I get the user ID to pass it into this function call? Do I need to get this information and pass it in, in my view layer?

This is my view layer:

```
@model MAA_v2.Models.tblPermission

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript">  </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Remove</legend>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Remove" name="Remove" class="button action-button "    />
            @Html.ActionLink("Back", "AdminIndex", "Maintenance", new { @class = "button action-button" })
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to Admin Maintenance", "AdminIndex")
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value is being passed from the http form, for example

```
<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="123">
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately that wasn't the only problem I need to solve, but that does help me out a'lot!

Comment: @SpaceJesus You are welcome. Don't forget there might be security issue with users forging requests, so you have to check if user really has right to delete passed `id`

Answer (score 0):

You can use an html helper for this. Assuming your view model has the property that contains the user id, then you can do this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        <p>
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
            <input type="submit" value="Remove" name="Remove" class="button action-button "    />
            @Html.ActionLink("Back", "AdminIndex", "Maintenance", new { @class = "button action-button" })
        </p>
}
```

Comment: This will not actually pass an id to the DeleteUser method.  You're invoking the wrong overload of ActionLink()